# Sql Server - Joining subqueries using calculated fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate the percentage change in price between days.  As the days are not consectutive, I build into the query a calculated field that tells me what relative day it is (day 1, day 2, etc).  In order to compare today with yesterday, I offset the calculated day number by 1 in a subquery.  what I want to do is to join the inner and outer query on the calculated relative day.  The code I came up with is:

```
SELECT TOP 11 
       P.Date,
       (AVG(P.SettlementPri) - PriceY) / PriceY as PriceChange, 
       P.Symbol,
       (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY P.Date desc)) as dayrank_Today
FROM OTE P
  JOIN (SELECT TOP 11 
               C.Date, 
               AVG(SettlementPri) as PriceY, 
               (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C.Date desc))+1 as dayrank_Yest
          FROM OTE C
         WHERE C.ComCode = 'C-' 
      GROUP BY c.Date) C ON dayrank_Today = C.dayrank_Yest
WHERE P.ComCode = 'C-' 
GROUP BY P.Symbol, P.Date
```

If I try and execute the query, I get an erro message indicating dayrank_Today is an invalid column.  I have tried renaming it, qualifying it, yell obsenities at it and I get squat. Still an error.

Comment: what db are you using? sql server?

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand your question. Can you provide us with the table structure (relevant fields only), input data, desired query result? Ideally you need to provide the script that creates tables and populates them with sample data.

Comment: @M.R.: `TOP` is SQL Server; `RANK` means SQL Server 2005+

Comment: `AVG(P.SettlementPri)` is the average per `Symbol` & `Date`, but `PriceY` is the average by `Date` only. Is this all right to compare the two? Is that not a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do a select of a calculated column, and then use it in a join. You can use CTEs, which I'm not so familiar with, or you can jsut do table selects like so:

```
SELECT 
     P.Date,       
     (AVG(AvgPrice) - C.PriceY) / C.PriceY as PriceChange, 
     P.Symbol,       
     P.dayrank_Today FROM
(SELECT TOP 11 
       ComCode,
       Date,
       AVG(SettlementPri) as AvgPrice,
       Symbol,
       (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Date desc)) as dayrank_Today
FROM OTE WHERE ComCode = 'C-') P 
  JOIN (SELECT TOP 11 
               C.Date, 
               AVG(SettlementPri) as PriceY, 
               (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C.Date desc))+1 as dayrank_Yest
          FROM OTE C
         WHERE C.ComCode = 'C-' 
      GROUP BY c.Date) C ON dayrank_Today = C.dayrank_Yest 
GROUP BY P.Symbol, P.Date
```

Comment: M.R. Thanks for the quick response. I tried your code but unfortunately get an error saying PriceY cannont be bound.

Comment: M.R. I'm new using Stackoverflow so I futzing things up a bit.  I provided more info my editing your response.  If thats the wrong way to do things, just let me know.

Comment: @GoingBaldBySql - it would be better to update your question rather than edit this answer. However, don't remove your existing code and make it clear that you are responding to this answer.

Comment: @GoingBalBySql: Can you tell me which PriceY bound is failing? Chances are I didn't get your field names right...i.e. does PriceY belong to the OTE table, or its the dervided column in the second table select?

Comment: @GoingBalBySql: I edited my response based on the assumption that PriceY is the derived column from OTE - give this a try...

Comment: Your `P` subquery mixes aggregating with non-aggregated columns but does not introduce GROUP BY. This cannot work in SQL Server.

Comment: @andriy M: correct - @goingBaldBySql, you should add a 'group by' to both the subselects..

Answer (score 3):

If possible consider using a CTE as it makes it very easy. Something like this:

```
With Raw as
(
    SELECT TOP 11 C.Date,
    Avg(SettlementPri) As PriceY,
    Rank() OVER (ORDER BY C.Date desc) as dayrank
    FROM OTE C WHERE C.Comcode = 'C-'
    Group by C.Date
) 

select today.pricey as todayprice ,
yesterday.pricey as yesterdayprice,
(today.pricey - yesterday.pricey)/today.pricey * 100 as percentchange 
from Raw today
left outer join Raw yesterday on today.dayrank = yesterday.dayrank + 1
```

Obviously this doesn;t include the symbol but that can be included pretty easily.
If using  'With' syntax doesn;t suit you can also use calculated fields with Outer Apply http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx

Although the CTE will mean that you only need to write your price calculation once which is a lot cleaner

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found this thread and found a solution so I thought I'd post it here.

Instead of using the column name as parameter for **ON**, copy the statement that gave you the colmun name in the first place:

replace:

```
ON dayrank_Today = C.dayrank_Yest
```

with:

```
ON (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Date desc)) = C.dayrank_Yest
```

Granted, you're displeasing the Programming Gods by violating [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but you could be pragmatic and mention the duplication in the comments, which should appease their wrath to a mild grumbling.